# Distributed database, many lightly loaded nodes

Tags: couchdb, cassandra, distributed

I'm working on a hobby project involving a rather CPU-intensive calculation. The problem is embarrassingly parallel. This calculation will need to happen on a large number of nodes (say 1000-10000). Each node can do its work almost completely independently of the others. However, the entire system will need to answer queries from outside the system. Approximately 100000 such queries per second will have to be answered. To answer the queries, the system needs some state that is sometimes shared between two nodes. The nodes need at most 128MB RAM for their calculations.

Obviously, I'm probably not going to afford to actually build this system in the scale described above, but I'm still interested in the engineering challenge of it, and thought I'd set up a small number of nodes as proof-of-concept.

I was thinking about using something like Cassandra and CouchDB to have scalable persistent state across all nodes. If I run a distributed database server on each node, it would be very lightly loaded, but it would be very nice from an ops perspective to have all nodes be identical.

Now to my question:

Can anyone suggest a distributed database implementation that would be a good fit for a cluster of a large number of nodes, each with very little RAM?

Cassandra seems to do what I want, but http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraHardware talks about recommending at least 4G RAM for each node.

I haven't found a figure for the memory requirements of CouchDB, but given that it is implemented in Erlang, I figure maybe it isn't so bad?

Anyway, recommendation, hints, suggestions, opinions are welcome!

Comment: You have described your cpu requirements, but not your data requirements.  Is the data large enough you need to spread it over a thousand nodes, how much data per node, do your calculations need a large amount of data such that running the calculations on the same node as the data is required, do queries need to access data stored on disk, or are queries served by result of the calculations, what is the relationship between data, queries and calculation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

The thing is, the data is very small. Total ammount of data stored in system is about 100 megabyte. The only reason not to store it in a single central node, is that the number of transactions to this data is a little bit too high for a single server to handle it.

Comment: How often does the data change?  Who changes the data?  How soon after the data changes do nodes need to see the changes?  What are the consistency requirements?

Comment: There are 1 million records, and each of them changes approximately once a minute, worst case. The data is changed as a result of a very expensive calculation, done for clients accessing the system from the outside. When the data changes, the next access (which may be within one second), MUST see the  new data. Consistency is trivial, the records are all independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with cassandra, though depending on your reliability requirements, an in memory database like redis might be more appropriate.

Since the data set is so small (100 MBs of data), you should be able to run with less than 4GB of ram per node.  Adding in cassandra overhead you probably need 200MB of ram for the memtable, and another 200MB of ram for the row cache (to cache the entire data set, turn off the key cache), plus another 500MB of ram for java in general, which means you could get away with 2 gigs of ram per machine.

Using a replication factor of three, you probably only need a cluster on the order of 10's of nodes to serve the number of reads/writes you require (especially since your data set is so small and all reads can be served from the row cache).  If you need the computing power of 1000's of nodes, have them talk to the 10's of cassandra nodes storing you data rather than try to split cassandra to run across 1000's of nodes.

Comment: I think you're right, the design I was proposing was rather silly - it's much better to have 10s of efficiently utilized servers, rather than having 1000 nodes with almost no load.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used CouchDB myself, but I am told that Couch will run in as little as 256M with around 500K records. At a guess that would mean that each of your nodes might need ~512M, taking into account the extra 128M they need for their calculations. Ultimately you should download and give each a test inside a VPS, but it does sound like Couch will run in less memory than Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after doing some more read-up after posting the question, and trying some thing out, I decided to go with MongoDB.

So far I'm happy. I have very little load, and MongoDB is using very little system resources (~200MB at most). However, my dataset isn't nearly as large as described in the question, and I am only running 1 node, so this doesn't mean anything.

CouchDB doesn't seem to support sharding out-of-the-box, so is not (it turns out) a good fit for the problem described in the question (I know there are addons for sharding).